# Viewport shading cannot use scene lights

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

No matter what I select, it's lit by emission or something, scene lights have no effect on it, adding a sun, turning off a sun, no difference, it's as on images, and no shadows.
Thank you, sorry for this noob question.
Max

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: It's hard to tell without more info. You should take a look at the shader nodes of the material. Did you use the *Node Wrangler* addon to get a preview of one of the nodes? It reconnects the material output to a *Viewer* node. This node is just an *Emission* node and could be the reason for this.

Comment: thank you, i finally had a pro look at it and he said: 
==
I think the guy who make this avatar has to fix this. the nodes look complex. And I can't locate what texture is connected to what.
==
so i'll just have to do without on this blend.

great username!